# How do i filter empty column in powerapps

Tags: powerapps

Here is my code am trying to display all data records that have no empty values in Image column from my table in a gallary but its failing.

SortByColumns(Search(Filter(InspectionImages,Image!=""), TextSearchBox1.Text,"Machine"), "Machine", Ascending)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<>` operator for that:

```
SortByColumns(
    Search(
        Filter(InspectionImages, Image <> ""),
        TextSearchBox1.Text,
        "Machine"),
    "Machine",
    Ascending)
```

If the image can be null (and not only empty) you can also add this:

```
SortByColumns(
    Search(
        Filter(InspectionImages, Image <> "", Image <> Blank()),
        TextSearchBox1.Text,
        "Machine"),
    "Machine",
    Ascending)
```